# Search a file till some matching found then continue again with search till end of the line

Tags: python

```
abc 
123
234
567
acb
d23
678
c34
aad
443
c66
78d
```

I need to write a loop that starts to read the file. As soon as it see a line start with "a", it will go through all lines below "a" until it finds another  line starting with "a" and will create a dictionary like below:

`{ "abc": [123,234,567], "acb": [d23,678,c34], "aad": [443,c66,78d] }`

I am very new to python and I am creating a script which has very
similar challenges.

Comment: Let us see your code

Comment: The honest answer I can give you: Your question is too broad to be answered directly without writing your whole program for you. Since we're not a free code writing service, we won't do that. 
It is not very hard to do this in python, but you will need to be able to program python at least a bit. Go to python.org, follow the basic tutorial.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Thanks, may be it looks like a homework but its not, I am a system admin and want to implement some script in python  ,the question i have asked its just a beginning of a problem ,i have long way to go, but if i can get some beginning help then i should be able to figure out my self.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that I had understood your problem correctly,please correct me if I misunderstood you 
Suppose your data is in file named **t.txt**

```
import re
f = open("t.txt")
text = f.read()

answer_dict = {}
value_list = []
key = ""
for line in text.split("\n"):
    print line
    if re.search('^a', line) != None:
        value_list = []
        key = ""
        key = line
    else:
        value_list.append(line)
        answer_dict[key] = value_list

print answer_dict

{'acb': ['d23', '678', 'c34'], 'abc ': ['123', '234', '567'], 'aad': ['443', 'c66', '78d']}
```

Comment: Hi Prashant, 
Thank you very much for the code, I  have almost completed my script, I will share the final script here , but can you just help me with one request,
if i want to find the Key by providing value, how do i do that ?
example, if want to search the dictionary by providing value 234, how will i get Key 'abc'

Comment: Basically this, i was expecting result "abc" for value "123"



    `for k, v in answer_dict.iteritems():
          print k,v
          if str(v) == "123":
                print "They key is:"
                print k
          else:
                print "No Key Found"`

out put :-
acb ['d23', '678', 'c34']
No Key Found
abc  ['123', '234', '567']
No Key Found
aad ['443', 'c66', '78d', '']
No Key Found

Comment: try this                                                                                                    flag = 1                                                                                                 for k, v in answer_dict.iteritems():                                                          print k,v                                                                                                    if str(v) == "123": print "They key is:" print k flag = 0                                if flag:print "No Key Found"

Comment: here if flag: print "No Key Found" is outside of "for loop"

Comment: Hi
I am trying bellow code, but it does not give the key .Thanks for your help

`flag = 1
for k, v in answer_dict.iteritems():
        print k,v
        if str(v) == "123":
            print k
            flag = 0
if flag:
 print "No Key Found"
`

Comment: I am relly sry check this one    flag = 1 for k, v in answer_dict.iteritems(): print k,v if "123" in v : print "They key is:" print k flag = 0 if flag:print "No Key Found"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to split into groups using lines that start with `"a"` as the delimiter:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("in.txt") as f:
    # use itertools.imap for python2
    grps = groupby(map(str.rstrip,f), key=lambda x: x[0] == "a")
    d = {}
    for k,v in grps:
        if k:
            k = next(v)
            d[k] = list(next(grps,["", ""])[1])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'acb': ['d23', '678', 'c34'], 'aad': ['443', 'c66', '78d'], 'abc': ['123', '234', '567']}
```

or using a regular loop start an inner loop when you find a line starting with `a`:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d,f,k = {}, map(str.rstrip, f),None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("a"):
            k = line
            d[k] = []
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith("a"):
                    k = line
                    d[k] = []
                    break
                d[k].append(line)
        elif k:
            d[k].append(line)
```

Which will output the same. I presume there should always be a section following any line starting with `a` but if not `list(next(grps,["", ""])[1])` will set the value to an empty list of there is none.

Comment: Hi Padraic, Thanks for both technique, Can you just tell me, whats the uses of Map ? i see its uses quite a lot

Comment: @FAlam, it maps a function across whatever iterable you pass to it, in this case we rstrip off all the newlines, you call `line.rstrip()` on each line inthe loops bit map is actually faster